# What does WoW's fishing depends on and how to catch Felblight?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

**What does WoW's fishing result depends on?**

The obvious dependence is location. Also I heard that at some locations your catch is limited by fishing level and you will catch a junk if the level is not high enough, but I never saw this, is this still the case?
Also I wonder if the catch depends on precise place where you stand, if there a school or not?

This is a general question, but I also have more specific one: **How to fish Felblight effectively?**.
I catch 1 Felblight out of ~750 tries and this looks like too small chance to do it. Any advices on how to improve it?

Comment: Wowhead comment section (http://www.wowhead.com/item=127759/felblight#comments) has anecdotal evidence that schools have a higher catch rate than open water. Haven't found anything definitive on whether or not fishing skill level affects rate, but Devs said it didn't for other gathering professions: https://twitter.com/WarcraftDevs/status/611289768568078336

Comment: The fishing drop rate was so low for Felblight that I gave up and went to farming Kazzak. This gets me around 90 per week, with 10 level 100 alts.

Answer (score 1):

You can only fish up Felblight from schools in Tanaan Jungle. There is no confirmation one way or the other as to whether skill level affects the catch rate for it, but it seems unlikely as pool catches were changed in 3.1.0 to be unaffected by Fishing skill, and other sources of Felblight are not affected by skill (including Mining and Skinning).

Comment: I've caught Felblight with fishing as low as 100-ish skill.